# how I find un subtle bug

Tags: c

I don't understand why the variable have value of 0, it should be 23?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int array[] = {23, 34, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16};
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int main(){
    int d = -1, x = 0;
    if (d <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2)
        x = array[d + 1];
    printf("x= %d \n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is of unsigned type. What happens if you compare a signed value `d` with an unsigned value `TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2`? You can also try an experiment: `if (d <= (int)TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2)`.

Comment: Try to narrow down your possibilities. Use parentheses if in doubt of operation priorities. First try to assign d=0 and have it print x as 23 then slowly work back towards your goal.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the **usual arithmetic conversions**.

When the operands of a operator involve both a signed integer and an unsigned integer, and the unsigned type is at least as large as the signed type, the signed value is converted to an unsigned value.  When the signed value is negative, it gets converted to a large positive value.

The rules for integer conversions are spelled out in section 6.3.1.8p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>   integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>   with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has 
>   rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other 
>   operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>   type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned
>   integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>   integer type

In this expression:

```
(d <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2)
```

Which expands to:

```
(d <= (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])) - 2)
```

The `sizeof` operator evaluates to a value of type `size_t` which is unsigned.  So the types of the operands look like this:

```
(int <= ((size_t / size_t) - int)
```

Both operands of the `/` operator are of type `size_t` so the result of that operation is of type `size_t`.  Then the right operand of `-` is converted to type `size_t`.  Since the value 2 fits in that type the value doesn't change.

Now we have the `<=` operator with an `int` on one size and a `size_t` on the other.  The left operand is converted from `int` to `size_t`, however the value -1 doesn't fit in that type so it is converted.  The converted value is actually the largest possible value for a `size_t` which is therefore greater than the value on the right side, making the result of `<=` false.

To fix this, you'll want to cast the unsigned value on the right to signed to prevent the left side from being converted:

```
if (d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2))
```

Comment: Or test what is used:  `if (d + 1 < TOTAL_ELEMENTS)`.

Comment: The crucial "left operand is converted from `int` to `size_t`" skips over a subtle point:  `size_t` certainly has a greater or equal rank to `int`.  It is _not_ specified in C to be so - but is so in OP's case.  I have never come across an implementation where `SIZE_MAX < INT_MAX` and doubt we ever will.  Still UV.